# React-circular-progressbar transition animation not wokring for value>=80

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, npm

I am trying to use the CircularProgressBar everything is working perfectly but the issue is if the value is greater than 80 the transition I added through styles does not work whereas if the value is anywhere between 1-79 the transition(animation is working fine)

[image]

On First load and refreshing the page the progress-bar just instantly loads no transition whatsoever the other styling works as expected.

I have created a reproducible example but its working properly on codesandbox not sure why its not working with my app,
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-circular-progressbar-issue-template-forked-n36u81?file=/index.js
here is how I am using the package:

```
<CircularProgressbar
   key={id}
   value={percent}
   strokeWidth={6}
   styles={{
      root: {
         height: "79px",
         width: "79px",
         position: "absolute",
         top: "50%",
         left: "50%",
         transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
         willChange: "transform",
       },
      path: {
        stroke: "#0b66ef",
        strokeLinecap: "round",
        transition: "stroke-dashoffset 15s ease",
    },
}}
    />
```

Tried On multiple browsers such as Brave, Chrome,etc
Version- 2.1.0

Comment: Since it's working in codesandbox, are there any other CSS styles being applied in your local app that might affect the component, other than the styles.modules.scss file?

Comment: @heyitsjhu i don't think so , the main issue is being that the transition works if the value < 80 , with same jsx and styling only if it goes above 80 the transition does not work not sure why